# Can we load the Wikidata dumps to AWS Neptune and query using Gremlin?

Tags: amazon-s3, gremlin, wikidata, amazon-neptune

Is it possible to load the [Wikidata dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/) into AWS Neptune and query the data using Apache TinkerPop Gremlin?

Is there a straight-forward way to load the json/ttl/nt dumps into Neptune (or) should the dumps be in Gremlin format?

Comment: It is possible to write code which parses the data dump. It is possible to write code to import data into AWS Neptune. It is possible to query Neptune with Gremlin. So yes, it is possible. What are you really asking?

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to ask if there is a straight-forward way to load the json/ttl/nt dumps into Neptune (or) should the dumps be in Gremlin format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Neptune supports both RDF and Labeled Property Graph frameworks, it is not currently possible to load data in an RDF format and query with any of the Property Graph query languages.  You would need to transform the Wikidata dumps into Neptune's CSV format for Property Graph [1] first.  Then you could load this data and query via Gremlin or openCypher (the two supported Property Graph query languages).

Comment: [1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format-gremlin.html