# SPARQL query on Wikidata - How to get people who are alive while there is no isDead property? Also, how to identity people as they belong to a country

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How to get the following data from Wikidata using SPARQL?

Result set 1:

List of all people who are male

Result set 2:

Take Result Set 1 as the source and then apply filter to get only the Men who are alive

Can we say if a person is alive if the dateOfDeath is not present?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel
WHERE
{
       ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . # human
       ?person wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097 . # man
       FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?person  wdt:P570  [] } # alive
  
       SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr,en" }
}
LIMIT 20
```

Result set 3:

Take Result Set 2 as the source and then apply filter to get only the Living-Men who are South Africans (a player might be from other country and played for South Africa in International Cricket. Those players should be excluded)

I don't suppose just Country of Citizenship would suffice.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel
WHERE
{
       ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 . # human
       ?person wdt:P21 wd:Q6581097 . # man
       FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?person  wdt:P570  [] } # alive
       ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q258 . # Country of citizenship - South Africa
  
       SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr,en" }
}
LIMIT 20
```

Result set 4:

Take Result Set 3 as the source and then apply filter to get only the Living-South-African-Men who are Cricketers (a cricketer might also be a politician. Those players should be included)

Result set 5:

Take Result Set 4 as the source and then apply filter to get only the Living-South-African-Male-Cricketers who are below 30 years of age (as on today)

I want these 5 queries to be executed in the exact same order. Could you help me get these results, please?

Comment: this is homework, right?

Comment: 2) there is indeed no other way besides assuming the absence of death date/place property is an indicator

Comment: 3) why not? what else would make a person South African a citizen? Sure, you could also take "place of birth" property and then check if that place is in country South Africa

Comment: 4) to keep it simple you can just look for "occupation" property with value "cricketer"

Comment: 5) get the birth date via Wikidata property and the current date via `now()`, then compute the age via `BIND( YEAR(?today) - YEAR(?birth_date) - 
              IF(MONTH(?today)<MONTH(?birth_date) || 
                 (MONTH(?today)=MONTH(?birth_date) && DAY(?today)<DAY(?birth_date)),1,0) AS ?age )`